# How can we mine first block on bitcoin fork?

Tags: altcoin

We have created our altcoin and genesis block for educational purposes, but we couldn't start the mining process. Because of internal miner has been removed from bitcoin source, we can't mine. We have tried with cgminer, but because of cgminer asks getblocktemplate and gets response LEARNcoin is downloading blocks. So my question is how can we mine the first block without internal miner?